# Java servlet not firing onSubmitComplete (Google app engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, gwt

GWT 2.5.1/
App Engine SDK 1.8.9

I am trying to upload a .CVS file to a servlet to be parsed using a FormPanel however I am getting no response from the servlet.

### Client code

```
// Create a FormPanel and point it at a service
    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "uploadServlet");
    System.out.println(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "uploadServlet");
            //gives me http:// . .  . /healthybc/uploadServlet

    // set form to use the POST method, and multipart MIME encoding
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.setWidget(buttonPanel);


    final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    fileUpload.setName("Browse");
    buttonPanel.add(fileUpload);

    // Add a 'submit' button.
    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            form.submit();                              
        }
    });

    buttonPanel.add(submit);

    // Add an event handler to the form.
    form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can take
            // this opportunity to perform validation.

            if (fileUpload.getFilename().length() == 0) {
                Window.alert("The text box must not be empty");
                event.cancel();
            }
            else if (!fileUpload.getFilename().endsWith(".csv")){
                Window.alert("Can only upload .csv files");
                event.cancel();
            }

        }
    });

    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
          // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
          // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
          // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
          // further explanation).

          Window.alert(event.getResults());
        }
      });
```

I get windows appearing from onSubmit() but no response from onSubmitComplete.

### web.xml

revelant web.xml code

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadedCSVParser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ca.ubc.cs310.gwt.healthybc.server.UploadedCSVParser
    </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadedCSVParser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/healthybc/uploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### Server code

```
public class UploadedCSVParser extends HttpServlet{   
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    out.println("<html>");
             out.println("<head>");
             out.println("<title> servlet title</title>");
             out.println("</head>");
              out.println("<body>");
              out.println("</body>");

         out.println("TEXT GOES HERE");

                out.println("</html>");
                out.close();


}
```

Right now the server code is just there to see if I actually get a response.
Directly typing in the URL ..."/healthybc/uploadServlet" in my browser (I am using firefox) gives me the expected "TEXT GOES HERE" output, but I receive no indication that onSubmitComplete ever runs when the form is submitted. I'm starting to think that the information never reaches the servlet.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any easy way for me to check if the servlet is actually being evoked?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it somehow. I redid the client side from a known working template and I think it might be in a slightly different order than what I originally had it.

```
    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setAction("/healthybc/uploadServlet");

        // then there's a button they can click which calls form.submit();
    form.setWidget(new Button("Submit", (new ClickHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        form.submit();
      }
    })));

    buttonPanel.add(form);

    final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    fileUpload.setName("Browse");
    buttonPanel.add(clinicFileUpload);

    // Add an event handler to the form.
    form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can take
            // this opportunity to perform validation.

            if (fileUpload.getFilename().length() == 0) {
                Window.alert("The text box must not be empty");
                event.cancel();
            }
            else if (!fileUpload.getFilename().endsWith(".csv")){
                Window.alert("Can only upload .csv files");
                event.cancel();
            }

        }
    });

    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
          // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
          // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
          // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
          // further explanation).
          Window.alert(event.getResults());
        }
      });
```